# trouble linking cpp/hpp from cmake

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

There's zillions of questions on this, but nothing I have read has helped me to resolve my problem.

I am working on unit testing on a large project, so there are multiple CMakeLists.txt files. I created a "utilities.cpp" file which grew quickly, so I decided to split it into test_utilities.cpp and test_utilities.hpp. When I `#include test_utilities.cpp` there is joy, but if I `#include test_utilities.hpp` the build fails:

```
Linking CXX executable foo
CMakeFiles/foo.dir/src/foo.cpp.o: In function `foo::bar()':
/mydir/trunk/tests/src/foo.cpp:57: undefined reference to `exit_on_invalid_config(std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,     std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >&)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [tests/foo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [tests/CMakeFiles/foo.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I think this is because the hpp and cpp are not being linked.

I have tried adding this to CMakeLists.txt:

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(utilities src/test_utilities.cpp src/test_utilities.hpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(utilities
    some_project
    test_main
    boost_program_options)
```

(actually this was here before, minus the hpp part, when I was including utilities.cpp, before I added the header file). This change does not help, so I tried adding

```
ADD_LIBRARY(test_utilities src/test_utilities.cpp src/test_utilities.hpp)
```

and included test_utilities into TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES:

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(foo src/foo.cpp)                                                   
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(foo
    some_project
    test_main
    test_utilities
    boost_program_options)
```

But when I try this, I get errors about boost crap being redefined. When I remove boost imports from foo.cpp, test_utilities.cpp/hpp I either get the same output or complaints that it can't find boost definitions.

What I would like CMake to do is compile the test_utilities executable (cpp + hpp) so that I don't get undefined reference when I try to import test_utilities.hpp from foo.cpp.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit: another issue I am having is, I'll add the executable test_utilities, but it doesn't get built before foo. I feel like this is part of my problem and I haven't figured out how to get test_utilities to build first.

Edit: Resolved thanks to wojciii! My issue boiled down to, I was importing boost unit test in test_utilities.cpp, test_main.cpp, and foo.cpp. I needed to stop doing that, fix dependency issues in my hpp, and tweak CMakeLists.txt a little.

Comment: "What I would like CMake to do is compile test_utilities.cpp, link it with test_utilities.hpp, and import test_utilities.hpp from foo.cpp without the undefined reference crap." - You do not link  with a header file. That makes no sense. I suggest that you try to edit your question and explain what it is that you want help with. :)

Comment: Ok, I have my terminology wrong. It's worth mentioning I've only got a few months experience in C++. I thought the whole thing was, you compile the cpp to a .o, the hpp to a .o, and link them into an executable???

Comment: That is usually what you need to do and it works out of the box. Create a static library. Add an executable. Link the executable with the static library. This should give you a working executable.

Comment: do you have some example code I can follow? I'm not sure what I should be doing that I'm not doing. Thanks again by the way.

Comment: How about https://github.com/jameskbride/cmake-hello-world ?